# Minidump when add layer from arcgis server to QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-server

I am trying to add ArcGIS server to QGIS 2.18.4 and load the file. The file is working fine; unfortunately when I right click  the layer and save it. It always pops up the info like this: [image]

ArcGIS Server: http://services1.arcgis.com/7uJv7I3kgh2y7Pe0/arcgis/rest/services/CGP_Vector_Data/FeatureServer
Please help me. The file is really important; it is about Cambodian Genocide Project - Vector Datasets